# How to handle array values in sql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a personID array like this `(123,456,789,etc...)` What I want to do is to query like this `SELECT * FROM tblperson WHERE personID <> '123' or personID <> '456' or personID <> '789'`

Note that the personID i want to get is from dynamic array. Thanks!

Comment: That query will return all personID's... Use `AND` instead of `OR`. Or `NOT IN` as in fa06's query-

Comment: What's the ACTUAL technology(-ies) being used here? What's with the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use not in

```
SELECT * FROM tblperson WHERE personID not in ( 123 ,456 , 789)
```

As you are using javascript, try below code to generate your query

```
var ids = [123 ,456 , 789];
var query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id not IN (' + ids.join() + ')';
```

Comment: my array name is `personArray()` How can I achieve your answer? @fa06

Comment: modify the answer - check it. my above query will work in any db, but as you are using it from javascript, first you need to generate the query from it